# Upgrading to Tensorflow 1.3 Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow 1.3.0 as seen below and I have included cudnn64_6.dll in my %PATH%, along with installed CUDA 8.0, but I still get an error message when importing tensorflow. The error message is after the installation message below:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\alexz>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.3.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached protobuf-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached tensorflow_tensorboard-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached numpy-1.13.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.3.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached setuptools-36.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib==0.9999999 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, setuptools, protobuf, wheel, werkzeug, html5lib, markdown, bleach, numpy, tensorflow-tensorboard, tensorflow-gpu
Successfully installed bleach-1.5.0 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-2.6.9 numpy-1.13.1 protobuf-3.4.0 setuptools-36.2.7 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-gpu-1.3.0 tensorflow-tensorboard-0.1.5 werkzeug-0.12.2 wheel-0.29.0
```

Additionally, I have python 3.6 with anaconda and followed instruction on tensorflow's website to install everything. 
Error Message:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\My_Items\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Update: When I rename cudnn64_6.dll to cudnn64_5.dll it works but when I check the version it is 1.2.1 instead of 1.3.0, even though I downloaded tensorflow 1.3.0. The error message comes back if I use cudnn64_6.dll. Very confusing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while installing Tensorflow 1.3 a month ago.
I fixed it by installing CudNN 5.1 instead of 6.

NB : I just saw that latest version is 7 now, maybe it works (I haven't tried).

I hope it helps,